# How do I set the workbench render background colour in 2.8?

Tags: rendering, image, workbench-render-engine

I have set my render engine to workbench.
I have set my world viewport display to completely black.
In both solid and rendered view the background is black. 
If I render an image though I get a grey background. Does anyone know what settings I have missed. Thanks.

[image]

This is what I get.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to get.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is the correct setting to change the background color. Have you changed something in the color management settings?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question to add my colour management settings. I don't remember changing anything other than the lighting to flat.

Comment: My issue was a plane I had in the background that had a black material assigned. This was done for the cycles render. For some reason in Workbench render this showed up as light grey. Once I deleted my background plane this rendered black for the background.